# How to work with rich text in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a ms access 2013 database, Into my database I have a table, it looks samthing so :

[image]

my text1 Is an Ole Object date type, here's a rtf text.
elemple :

```
 {\rtf1 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af31507 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid14841988 Hello}}
```

if I write this text into rtf file and I open it with Word, the file Word have write "Hello" text. How can I create with msAccess 2013 an rtf file, or to show into a report this column text ?? Which is the best way to show this column text??? Thank you a lot

Comment: Please show us the code you are trying to use, or what you have tried

Comment: first I created a simple text box , I do it to have text format acTextFormatHTMLRichText and so I assign database value so :
Me.RTextBox.Value = Me!Text1 second I want to made a converted function RtfToText() but I don't  find somthing function created in ms access

Comment: Please edit your question, adding some more details from your comment (click the `edit` link under the tag)

Comment: OK, I try to explain so, I have a access 2003 database, I open it into access 2013, in my old database I have column datetype OLE Object, I can't show data from this column in Access 2013, access 2013 have not rtf control, how can I show this one?

Comment: Please *Click the* `edit` *link under the* `ms-access-2013` *tag* and add the extra information **to the question**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your best option for the future would be to

1. Upgrade the database from Access 2003 (.mdb) to Access 2013 (.accdb).
2. Add a new column named `Text1_NEW` as `Long Text` (previously known as `Memo`) with its `Text Format` property set to `Rich Text`.
3. Convert the RTF-encoded text from the `Text1` field into HTML-encoded text and save it in the `Text1_NEW` field.
4. Once you've verified that the conversion was successful, delete the `Text1` field and rename the `Text1_NEW` field to `Text1`.

Then you could use the "rich text" `Long Text` field with a regular Text Box control in Access 2013.

For an idea as to how you might actually convert the RTF-encoded text to HTML-encoded text, see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793781/2144390). That answer uses Word to save an RTF document to plain text, but it could just as easily save the document as HTML. Do note, however, that Word tends to produce rather bloated HTML documents, so check the results of a small test before performing a wholesale  conversion.

Comment: very nice, I don't do new column into database, I convert the rtf to plain text and I show into a text box, this is the best way because, I think, if the customer want to adding the table from the sql one more time, he want to do this with out problem for me, thank you a lot Mr. Thompson. very good conversion function.